# How can we clean old DB postgres data from heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework, migration

I have an posgresql database in heroku and I am doing playframework migrations.

I've reseted this database using

```
 heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

and also dropped all tables and evolutions. However, when I delete all my files from /conf/evolutions/defaults and try to set everything again, some old data persists, giving messages like

*ERROR: column "step_description" of relation "step" already exists [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42701]*

Comment: It might be easier to just remove the add-on and add another one for postgres!

Comment: Actually, I've done it by removing the app (removing the database and creating one does not solve this problem). However, it could be a huge problem if we need to change something in production...